# Expression not working on action GOTO Report pointing to the same report, changing parameter

Tags: asp.net, reporting, reportviewer, sql-server-express, goto

My Report (SQL Express 2008) has a parameter Value1 which is a text

I have a dataset (DS1) holding Value and Name shown in a table.

When I click on the value in the table, I use a GO TO Report action,

point at the same report, only append the Parameter Value1 with the clicked value and pass it.

Next, I want to hide the row, containing the value based on INSTR() function.

In the development environement it works oke.

Also in the reporting manager on the same server it works ok.

The problem appears when I want to use reportviewer in my ASP.Net application. (.Net 4.5 reportviewer 11.0.0.0 VS2012)

When i click the value, the textbox is filled with the right parameter, only it doesn't hide.

I have to click on "View Report" button once again for the expression to take place.

I also tried to use reportviewer 10.0.0 in VS 2010, same result.

Does someone know what to do ? This is absolutely crucial for my. Working already 2 weeks on it. No satisfying result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a timing issue, which I had to search for 2 weeks.

The solution was to just wait untill the report /web page is fully rendered in the browser.

Now i can reproduce this.

When I click too fast on the action button if fails to render correctly.

If i wait until rendering finished, there is no problem any more.